InvalidSubnet.Conflict when Changing Number of Availability Zones in AWS VPC Configuration
I’m working on a Terraform configuration for creating an AWS VPC and subnets, and I'm encountering an error when changing the number of availability zones (AZs) while decreasing or increasing it. The error message is as follows:
InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR 'xx.xx.x.xxx/xx' conflicts with another subnet
status code: 400

My Terraform configuration where I define the CIDR blocks and subnets:
locals {
  vpc_cidr_start             = "192.168"
  vpc_cidr_size              = var.vpc_cidr_size
  vpc_cidr                   = "${local.vpc_cidr_start}.0.0/${local.vpc_cidr_size}"
  cidr_power                 = 32 - var.vpc_cidr_size
  default_subnet_size_per_az = 27

  public_subnet_ips_num  = (var.use_only_public_subnet ? pow(2, 32 - local.vpc_cidr_size) : pow(2, 32 - local.default_subnet_size_per_az) * length(var.availability_zones))
  private_subnet_ips_num = var.use_only_public_subnet ? 0 : pow(2, 32 - local.vpc_cidr_size) - local.public_subnet_ips_num
  ips_per_private_subnet = format("%b", floor(local.private_subnet_ips_num / length(var.availability_zones)))
  ips_per_public_subnet  = format("%b", floor(local.public_subnet_ips_num / length(var.availability_zones)))
  private_subnet_cidr_size = tolist([
    for i in range(4, length(local.ips_per_private_subnet)) : (32 - local.vpc_cidr_size - i)
    if substr(strrev(local.ips_per_private_subnet), i, 1) == "1"
  ])
  public_subnet_cidr_size = tolist([
    for i in range(4, length(local.ips_per_public_subnet)) : (32 - local.vpc_cidr_size - i)
    if substr(strrev(local.ips_per_public_subnet), i, 1) == "1"
  ])

  subnets_by_az = concat(
    flatten([
      for az in var.availability_zones :
      [
        tolist([
          for s in local.private_subnet_cidr_size : {
            availability_zone = az
            public            = false
            size              = tonumber(s)
          }
        ]),
        tolist([
          for s in local.public_subnet_cidr_size : {
            availability_zone = az
            public            = true
            size              = tonumber(s)
          }
        ])
      ]
    ])
  )

  subnets_by_size    = { for s in local.subnets_by_az : format("%03d", s.size) => s... }
  sorted_subnet_keys = sort(keys(local.subnets_by_size))
  sorted_subnets = flatten([
    for s in local.sorted_subnet_keys :
    local.subnets_by_size[s]
  ])
  sorted_subnet_sizes = flatten([
    for s in local.sorted_subnet_keys :
    local.subnets_by_size[s][*].size
  ])

  subnet_cidrs = length(local.sorted_subnet_sizes) > 0 && local.sorted_subnet_sizes[0] == 0 ? [
    local.vpc_cidr
  ] : cidrsubnets(local.vpc_cidr, local.sorted_subnet_sizes...)

  subnets = flatten([
    for i, subnet in local.sorted_subnets :
    [
      {
        availability_zone = subnet.availability_zone
        public            = subnet.public
        cidr              = local.subnet_cidrs[i]
      }
    ]
  ])


  private_subnets_by_az = { for s in local.subnets : s.availability_zone => s.cidr... if s.public == false }
  public_subnets_by_az  = { for s in local.subnets : s.availability_zone => s.cidr... if s.public == true }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  count  = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id = local.vpc_id
  cidr_block              = local.public_subnets_by_az[var.availability_zones[count.index]][0]
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zones[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = merge(
    {
      Name = "${var.cluster_name}-public-subnet-${count.index}"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count  = var.use_only_public_subnet ? 0 : length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id = local.vpc_id
  cidr_block              = local.private_subnets_by_az[var.availability_zones[count.index]][0]
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zones[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags = merge(
    {
      Name = "${var.cluster_name}-private-subnet-${count.index}"
    }
  )
}

Are there any specific areas in the CIDR block calculations I should focus on to prevent overlapping subnets?

It's the subnet group that conflicts, you give big blocks to each subnet so you should take bigger steps between them. It doesn't really matter, just make sure that you take enough space between each block so no conflict.

There should be an easier way to do what you want, for example by using the cidrsubnets built-in function.

@avifen Do you mean the default_subnet_size_per_az that has been added?

In general, your calculation is very complex and error-prone, I did not fully debug it. But you can use something like offered above your comment, simplify the calculation, simply take a bigger margin. If nothing works, debug it with echo or by changing it from one step for all to incremental steps to see where it fails so you know where the issue is.
